# Is there a shortcut for going to a module in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

The project I work on has hundred of modules within multiple nested folders. Having to navigate through the project tree to go to a module is rather slow.

**Is there a command where I can start typing and it'll give me the best module matches?**

Find Files displays modules, but it is polluted by thousands of files, meaning that I have to give nearly the exact module name to get it. I was looking for something similar but that looks for only modules.

Also, if I click on the project tree and start typing, it doesn't match modules in which its folder is closed, which doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really mean modules or just classes but I think `Search everything` will help you.

Just press the `SHIFT` key 2 times and enter the name of what you look for and it will show what you need.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, Find Files (or Search everything) displays modules, but it is polluted by thousands of files, meaning that I have to give nearly the exact module name to get it. I was looking for something similar but that looks for only modules so that I can have a more loose search.

Comment: you can use "Find in Path" dialog (ctrl+shift+f) where you can select "Module" and see the list of them. Start typing and Intellij IDEA will try to locate the matching modules.